# Winscp assembly won't load in powershell: dependency missing

Tags: powershell, automation, dependencies, winscp, windows-server-2019

I'm encountering the following error when trying to run a script involving winscp automation.

```
Add-Type : Could not load file or assembly 
'file://\\~removed~\dfs\Repo\Scripts\ScheduledTasks\~removed~\WinSCP-Automation\WinSCPnet.dll' or one of its dependencies. 
Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)
At \\~removed~\dfs\Repo\Scripts\ScheduledTasks\~removed~\Start-Upload.ps1:19 char:1
+ Add-Type -Path (Join-Path $env:WINSCP_PATH "WinSCPnet.dll")
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-Type], FileLoadException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.FileLoadException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCommand
```

The code in question that gets this error:

```
#Dependencies 
$Path = '\\redacted\dfs\Repo\Scripts\ScheduledTasks\redacted'
Set-Location -Path $Path
$env:WINSCP_PATH = '.\WinSCP-Automation'
Add-Type -Path (Join-Path $env:WINSCP_PATH "WinSCPnet.dll")
```

Basically we run a powershell script in task scheduler which uploads some data somewhere else using winscp.

This script works fine on the previous task scheduler box which is windows 2012 R2. But we built a windows 2019 box, copied everything over and we get the error above.

The winscp automation is being run off of the UNC path via the script.
I have also tried the latest version of the winscp assembly from that unc path but also tried loading it in to the script from a local directory on the box.

However I shake it it always gets this error. I have also installed versions of vs c++ redistributables that were on the 2012r2 box and confirmed the .net Framework versions.The DLL and all winscp files are unblocked.

I tried running dependency walker but it's an outdated tool that doesn't really work for 2019 so I used another modern version on GitHub which did show me that I had all the dependencies needed.

I must also add that they are both using powershell 5.1, but the 2012 R2 is using a slightly older release. Both have the winscp powershell module installed too. I've tried using the alt versions of the DLL in the folder and also tried adding to GC.

I'm completely baffled and right down the rabbit hole, any guidance or support would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So I couldnt get it to work from UNC path with this but I was able to fix it using

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile('C:\Scripts\Redacted\WinSCP-Automation\WinSCPnet.dll')
```

Instead of

```
$env:WINSCP_PATH = '.\WinSCP-Automation'
Add-Type -Path (Join-Path $env:WINSCP_PATH "WinSCPnet.dll")
```

Not sure still why it works locally and not from the remote path and not sure why its working with this reflection assembly but I digress, the problem is solved.

Comment: It seems you have done two changes: 1) `Assembly.LoadFile` instead of `Add-Type` 2) Local path instead of UNC. I assume that only one of them was the actual fix. Which one? I guess the 2). It's not that surprising that you cannot load binaries from network paths.

Comment: Actually it was previously loading from the network path before setting up the windows 2019 task scheduler, (previously reaching out to network from 2012 R2). The answer is both as loading winscp locally didn't work until using `Assembly.Loadfile`. Loading from network path is possible as it was before I'm sure but I'm happy with it running locally.

Comment: So what error did you get when loading the assembly using `Add-Type` locally?

Comment: I got the same error described in the original question. And I have stated there that I tried locally too